# Logic to return continuous numbers lets say array with elements 1,9,2,3,4,9,6,7,8 then it should return 2,3,4,6,7,8?

Tags: c++, c

My code is below but there is some error can anyone guide me to write logic to return continuous numbers, for example, if `array[] = {1,3,5,2,3,4,7,4,5,6}` then function should return `2,3,4,4,5,6` keep time complexity in mind?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 10
int coll[max];

void call_sort(int* p) {
    int i = 0, first, sec;
    while (*p) {
        first = *p;
        p++;
        sec = *p - 1;
        if (first == sec) {
            coll[i] = *p;
            i++;
        }
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < max; j++) {
            printf("%d ", coll[j]);
            //coll=coll+1;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printf("ya\n");
    int buff[max], i;
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
        scanf("%d", buff[i]);
    call_sort(&buff);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please provide more information of what ouput are you expecting and what kind of error did you got.

Comment: Decide on the programming language, C **or** C++.  For example, in C++ you can use `std::vector` and `std::sort`.  Remove the appropriate tag.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no need to sort anything for this problem.

Comment: `int buff[max]... call_sort(buff);` --> `int buff[max+1] ...buff[i] = 0; call_sort(buff);` to insure last array element is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your code

1. Wrong parameter to `scanf()`, you need to pass the address of the variable to modify it inside `scanf()` like this

   ```
   scanf("%d", &buff[i]);
   ```

   and you should also check that `scanf()` did read the value correctly by checking it's return value.
2. Wrong parameter to `call_sort()`, this will not cause any problem in this case, but it's wrong, and this combined with the `scanf()` issue, means that you did not enable compiler warnings, you should.

   The correct way to pass `buff` is simply

   ```
   call_sort(buff);
   ```
3. Wrong `while (*p)` which assumes that `0` is the last element of the array.

   You should probably pass the size as a parameter and write a `for` loop, since you are dealing with numbers and `0` is a number, if it were a text string then it would be ok to exclude `0` from the normal values and use it as a sentinel value which is done in the standard library functions for strings.

Comment: can u please give the logic for above problem?

Comment: No, I just can do what I did, and you need to read a lot to write the program correctly if you can't I can do it if you pay me.

Comment: Dude  coz of ur attitude i finally did and i will show u for free      #include<stdio.h>
#define max 10
void call_sorted(int *p)
{
int coll[max],count=0,i=0,flag=0,k;
int first,sec,j;
for(j=0;j<max;j++)
{
first=p[j];
   j++;
  sec=p[j];
if((sec-first)==1)
{
coll[i]=first;
i++;

coll[i]=sec;
i++;
flag=1;
}
else if(flag==1 && (p[j-2]==(p[j-1]-1))) 
{
coll[i]=first;
i++;
}
else
j--;
}
printf("i===%d\n",i);
for(k=0;k<i;k++)
printf("%d\n",coll[k]);
}

int main()
{
int arr[max],i;
printf("enetr 10 integer\n");
for(i=0;arr[i];++i)
scanf("%d\n",&arr[i]);
call_sorted(arr);
}

Comment: Please remove the code from that comment, I am glad that you solved the problem, you can accept the answer if it helped you otherwise I can delete it.